# Installing JEDI in Delphi 10.3 Rio

Tags: delphi, jedi, jvcl

I am trying to get the JCL/JVCL to install in Delphi 10.3, previously I could use the getit package manager within Delphi to download it, but now it does not appear to be on the list? I have tried doing a manual download on the JVCL but when I try to install this I get a page of error messages from the compiler and nothing happens.

Thanks
Phil

Comment: What errors?  That might help us determine the problem.  I installed JCL/JVCL the other day on my machine with 10.3 Community and it worked fine.  It was not in the GetIt manager but I cloned the source and ran the install.bat.  It installed both the 32 bit and 64 bit components.  I even compiled one of my projects without any problem.

Comment: The one I downloaded from GitHub was JVCL349CompleteJCL27-Build5676.zip

It scrolls up lots of warnings tells me its installed and then when I go into the JVCL folder and run install it tells me the JCL is required but not installed.

Comment: I did the getit version from my last version but it tells me it cant use it as it's outdated.  And now getit doesn't even know it exists even if I delete it from the list of packages on my machine.

Comment: Hmmm... I used git and followed the directions in the readme.md file (can be viewed on GitHub) that worked nicely (an installer is compiled and then started, first for JCL, and once you get the JVCL, for that too). It installed for *all* versions I have installed here, for 32 bit and for 64 bit each. Not sure what the .zip file contains.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  thank you this worked.  I downloaded the git installer for windows and ran the depreciated cmd line version and now it installs :-)  Many thanks!

Comment: JCL zip file is missing jcl\source\include\jedi\jedi.inc. File can be found here: https://github.com/project-jedi/jedi/blob/master/jedi.inc

Answer (score 1):

@rudyvelthuis answer solved it.  Doesn't want to work from within Delphi at present.

To get it to work with Rio, use git (windows version) and clone and follow instructions.  Only thing to add is if you have a new install of windows 10 you will need to allow it to download the older .net framework as well.